# Visual Studio 11 (2012) beta to RC?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

What are the differences in Visual Studio 11 RC from beta? 11 is working for me at the moment (not flawless but ok) and i wanted to know if its worth the risk of reinstalling.

I particularly use C++ and C#. About 50-50 ATM.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ Intellisense is a lot better. It no longer complains about the range-based for loop, for example. In earlier betas I basically just ignored red wigglies because they were usually wrong, and I waited to see what the compiler had to say about it. I also like the touch of colour that was added to the toolbars. I don't care for the all caps menus, but you can turn those off with a registry edit.

Comment: "range-based for loop" The MS specific one or the new C++11 loops?

Comment: the new C++ 11 one `for(auto elem: v) {std::cout << elem << " ";}`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend upgrading, if for no other reason than the VS 2012 RC is going to be closer to the final RTM version.

For the most part, the main changes (other than some visual refreshing) seem to be some performance and bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Clean install is always the best method. You can run into some problems like that: [“Invalid License Data” after upgrading from Visual Studio 2012 Beta to RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2012/06/04/how-to-fix-invalid-license-data-after-upgrading-from-visual-studio-2012-beta-to-rc.aspx)

Visual Studio 2012 RC is more stable and reliable than Beta. Also the performance seems better. For example the setup takes 10 less minutes than the beta.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, xaml binding debugging is back (possible under vs 2010 using silverlight 5, but not possible under vs 11 beta silverlight 5).
Be careful, seems that the embedded blend for visual studio 2012 is usable only under Windows 8. But you can install Blend for silverlight 5 if required.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on Programmers: [VS 11 vs VS 2012](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155026/vs-11-vs-vs-2012), but didn't get any answers.

Anyway I decided to install 2012 RC, as I understand you can run installer without uninstalling VS 11 beta first. Running installation right now.